# PHP preg_replace pattern NOT ending in '.zip' or '.pdf' or '.txt'

Tags: php, regex

I want to preg_replace the following:

```
$string='<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah><img ><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" blah>';
```

I want to add a `target="_blank"` to every href which is NOT ending in `.zip` or `.pdf` or `.txt`

I tried a pattern like this: `$pattern='href="http.*(?!zip)"';` but does not work.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to make it blank by default and only add in the target if it ends in your chosen file formats.

Also, there are several regex builders available on line, you should at least try to make it first and then post again if it's not working.

Voting to close topic.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a dom parser instead and check if the href does not end with .zip and then add the target. The negative lookahead in `http.*(?!zip)` will be true as `.*` fill first match until the end of the string and zip will not be there at the right when it is already at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use PHP's built-in [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse and process HTML. Then you can simply fetch all `<a>` tags and check whether the `href` ends in `.zip` or `.pdf` or `.txt`, and if not, add a `target` attribute with value `_blank`:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html>$string</html>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    if (!preg_match('/(zip|pdf|txt)$/', $href)) {
        $a->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
}
echo substr($doc->saveHTML(), 6, -8);
```

Output:

```
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah2></a><img>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" blah2 target="_blank"></a>
```

Note that because you don't have a top-level element in the sample HTML, one (`<html>`) has to be added on read and then removed on output (using `substr`). If your actual HTML has a top-level element, you don't need to bother with that.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AEKTg)

If you *insist* on using regex, there's a regex in the demo too...

Answer (score 0):

As others already suggested above, it is better to use `DOM` parsing here.

The `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED`, `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` [predefinied constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) turns off the automatic adding of `html` and `body` elements and also the doctype when you use `saveHTML()`.

You can use `DOMXPath` query in order to collect your links that does **NOT** contain `zip`, `pdf` or `txt` references and modify the rest.

```
$string = '<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah><img ><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" blah>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = $xpath->query("//a[not(contains(@href,'zip')) and not(contains(@href,'pdf')) and not(contains(@href,'txt'))]");
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

print $dom->saveHTML();
```

***Results in***:

```
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip"><img><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" target="_blank"></a></a>
```

**NOTE**: The closing tags are not placed properly in this way. However if you add an opening `<div>` at the beginning of your string then the closing `</a>` tags are placed differently.

```
<div><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip"><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" target="_blank"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead pattern. Try this one

### Code:

```
<?php

$string='<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.pdf" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a>
<a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.pdf" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a>
<a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" blah><img></a>


<!-- One line -->
<a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" blah><img></a><a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" blah><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" blah><img></a>';

$string = preg_replace('/<a.+?href=\"(.+?)(\.(?!zip|pdf|txt)[^\.]+?)"/i', '$0 target="_blank"', $string);

echo $string;
```

### Output:

```
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.pdf" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a>
<a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" target="_blank" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" target="_blank" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zip" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.pdf" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a>
<a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" target="_blank" blah><img></a>
<a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" target="_blank" blah><img></a>


<!-- One line -->
<a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" target="_blank" blah><img></a><a href="http://example.com/readme.qwe" target="_blank" blah><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.txt" blah><img></a><a blah href="http://example.com/readme.zqp" target="_blank" blah><img></a>
```